# r programming - error in loadnamespace - package or namespace load failed

Tags: r

This might be a very basic question but I am not getting anything about this. I searched many approaches after googling and none of them worked for me.

The issue is that whenever I tried to load any default package like swirl or download any package and then source that to R, I am getting the error below.

```
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringi’
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’
```

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: You are missing the *stringi* package.  Do `install.packages("stringi")` then try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. All the time I was trying to install it by specifying a location and it didn't work. Just with name itself it worked this time.

Comment: It's good that you got success with your particular problem, but I was puzzled by the statement that the `swirl` package was a default.

Comment: @BondedDust it may be a language barrier related statement. Perhaps the user meant "packages I load when I start my document"?

Answer (score 0):

Install the "stringi" package first.

I had the same issue. Actually, there were two different packages mentioned in the error message: "stringi" and "stringr" packages. I misread the last letter and thought I had already installed the package.